# show the near by events after integrating Facebook SDK means Facebook login in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

How to show the near by events after integrating Facebook SDK means Facebook login in Android?

I have written this code:

```
AccessToken tok;
tok = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
//  login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes", "user_events", "read_stream"));

String id = tok.getUserId();
//  String id=getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id);
Log.d("--id", id);

new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/"+id+"/events", null, HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

            /* handle the result */
            Log.e("--result", response + "");

        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

in `onsuccess` of the callback method of Facebook SDK integration.

But it's showing:

> result: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[]}, error: null}

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.neelu.chatapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        facebookSDKInitialize();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        getLoginDetails(loginButton);
        getHashKey();
    }


    public void getHashKey() {
        try {

            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("--KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("name not found", e.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
        }
    }


    protected void facebookSDKInitialize() {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }

    protected void getLoginDetails(final LoginButton login_button) {

        // Callback registration
        login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult login_result) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomePage.class);
//                startActivity(intent);
//                AccessToken accessToken= login_result.getAccessToken();
//                Profile profile= Profile.getCurrentProfile();
//                if(profile!=null)
//                {
////                    textViewMessage.setText("welcome"+ profile.getName());
//                }

                AccessToken tok;
                tok = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
//                login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes", "user_events", "read_stream"));

                String id = tok.getUserId();
//                String id=getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id);
                Log.d("--id", id);
                new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/"+id+"/events", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */

                                Log.e("--result", response + "");
                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // code for cancellation
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                //  code to handle error
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("data", data.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: please help me by showing near by events in android facebook integration sdk???/??